# How to shorten the json path used to identify a single element within an array?

Tags: java, rest-assured

Please assume the following response

```
{
  "animals": [
    {
      "name": "hobba",
      "embeddedData": {
        "age": "3",
        "color": "white"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "obba",
      "embeddedData": {
        "age": "1",
        "color": "yellow"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to assert the existence of an element within the array with specific value. This is how I do it:

```
JsonPath jsonPath = response.jsonPath();
Assert.assertNotNull("Error message", jsonPath .param("name", "hobba").param("age", "3").param("color", "white").get("animals.find { a -> a.name == name && a.embeddedData.age == age && a.embeddedData.color == color"));
```

As you see, I have to type `a.embeddedData` before every element I need to assert it's value. This is just an example as there will be numerous elements to assert their values.

Is there a more readable and loop-friendly way to do this ?
Also what if there is an array within `embeddedData` or `animals`, how can I still perform assertions with each element in `animals` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check body using built-in assertion functionality with matchers:

```
.then()
    .assertThat()
    .root("animals.embeddedData")
    .body("age", Every.everyItem(Matchers.notNullValue()))
    .body("color", Every.everyItem(Matchers.notNullValue()))
```

Comment: But this doesn't assert values for `age` & `color` together for each `animal` element. I mean I need to make sure that there is an element with `age == 3 && color == white`. This is for a single element. Your code asserts the value for `age` alone for each element, and then for `color` alone for each element.

Comment: just replace `animals.embeddedData` with `animals[0].embeddedData` and `everyItem` with required matcher

Comment: Merging the information in your upper comment with `response.jsonPath().getList("animals").size();` solved my case. Thank you.